# change adonis template engine from edge to ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs, template-engine, adonis.js

I want to change Adonis template engine from `edge` to `ejs`.
I add this code in my `app.js` code

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
module.exports = { providers, aceProviders, aliases, commands,app }
```

but when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3333/tickets` show me this error.

> E_MISSING_VIEW: Cannot render tickets.edge. Make sure the file exists at E:\jodecms\resources\views location.

file `tickets.ejs` is exists in that folder but I don't know why template engine is not change to `ejs`

My `app.js` code:

```
'use strict'
const providers = [

  '@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider',
  '@adonisjs/framework/providers/ViewProvider',
  '@adonisjs/lucid/providers/LucidProvider',
  '@adonisjs/bodyparser/providers/BodyParserProvider',
  '@adonisjs/cors/providers/CorsProvider',
  '@adonisjs/shield/providers/ShieldProvider',
  '@adonisjs/session/providers/SessionProvider',
  '@adonisjs/auth/providers/AuthProvider',
  '@adonisjs/lucid/providers/LucidProvider'
]
 
const aceProviders = [
  '@adonisjs/lucid/providers/MigrationsProvider'
]
 
const aliases = {}
 const commands = [];
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
module.exports = { providers, aceProviders, aliases, commands,app }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and I think it should work:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Hope it helps - the error says that your app can't render/find your tickets.ejs (not tickets.edge!!) file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a path error and you need to set the ejs. Know that ejs files are meant to be stored in a folder called "views".

First you need to set the view engine preview with:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then you need to set the static path to a public folder which will nest the views folder which has the ejs you need to render. You need to create all these folders.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')));
```

I assume you have already done this and have your Node.js file inside public so inside the Node.js you just need to add the post/get request for the ejs. I have taken an example where "app.js" is the Nodejs file name and "admin.ejs" is the file I needed to render. "admin.ejs" was stored in a folder called "views" which I had create inside the public directory, you don't need to specify the views folder when making the post/get request because Nodejs will automatically look inside the default folder.

```
    app.get('/admin.ejs',(req, res) => {
    Order.find({}, function(err, movies) {
        res.render('admin.ejs', {
            moviesList: movies
        })
    })
})
```